# How can I calculate the mean of the top 4 observations in my column?

Tags: r, max, mean

How can I calculate the mean of the top 4 observations in my column?

```
c(12, 13, 15, 1, 5, 9, 34, 50, 60, 50, 60, 4, 6, 8, 12)
```

For instance, in the above I would have (50+60+50+60)/4 = 55. I only know how to use the quantile, but it does not work for this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

Since you're interested in only the top 4 items, you can use `partial sort` instead of full sort. If your vector is huge, you might save quite some time:

```
x <- c(12, 13, 15, 1, 5, 9, 34, 50, 60, 50, 60, 4, 6, 8, 12)
idx <- seq(length(x)-3, length(x))
mean(sort(x, partial=idx)[idx])
# [1] 55
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
vec <- c(12, 13, 15, 1, 5, 9, 34, 50, 60, 50, 60, 4, 6, 8, 12)

mean(sort(vec, decreasing=TRUE)[1:4])
```

gives

```
[1] 55
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
v <- c(12, 13, 15, 1, 5, 9, 34, 50, 60, 50, 60, 4, 6, 8, 12)
mean(head(sort(v,decreasing=T),4))
```

First, you `sort` your vector so that the largest values are in the beginning. Then with `head` you take the 4 first values in that vector, subsequently taking the mean value of that.

Answer (score 1):

To be different!  Also, please try to do some research on your own before posting.

```
x <- c(12, 13, 15, 1, 5, 9, 34, 50, 60, 50, 60, 4, 6, 8, 12)    
mean(tail(sort(x), 4))
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to show that you can use `quantile` in this exercise:

```
mean(quantile(x,1-(0:3)/length(x),type=1))
#[1] 55
```

However, the other answers are clearly more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the order function. Order by -x to give the values in descending order, and just average the first 4:

```
x <- c(12, 13, 15, 1, 5, 9, 34, 50, 60, 50, 60, 4, 6, 8, 12)

mean(x[order(-x)][1:4])
[1] 55
```